# Is there a way to list all required dynamic libraries by perl?

Tags: perl, shared-libraries

As we know many perl modules depends on some dynamic libraries to function,loaded by `DynLoader`(I don't know if there's any other way to load `.so` though).

```
./perl_programe
```

Is there a way to list all required dynamic libraries for a specific perl programe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
do shift;
print "$_\n" for @DynaLoader::dl_shared_objects;
```

It takes the script to check as first (and only) argument. e.g. `./dyna perl_programe`

Comment: It's a fairly evil trick. It does something similar to `include` in some other languages. See 'do EXPR' in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html for more information.

Comment: It seems to be broking the problem if the `perl_programe` is simply `<>;`.. It exits directly before I press enter.

Comment: It seems better to use `require` instead of `do` ,which is just for the job of `include`.. What do you think?

Comment: The difference would only matter if you'd try to apply the script to itself, which would be a bad idea anyways.

Comment: Are you sure of the difference? I just tried, and seems `do` is the same as `require` even if it's applying to itself...Say, it won't load a file twice.