# How to ensure my code never exits directly?

Tags: perl

```
eval{
   require $file;
}

/*subsequent code goes here*/
...
```

If `$file` contains an `exit` statement, the subsequent code doesn't have a chance to run.

How to work around so that the subsequent code always get its chance to run when `eval` is done??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to abort the `exit` call. `$file` should use `die` instead, which can be trapped by an `eval`.

As a workaround, you can override the `exit` builtin globally:

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = sub { die "About to exit" } 
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference b/w `do $file` and `require $file`? For more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872732/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-required-dynamic-libraries-by-perl/6873195#6873195

Comment: Note that this will break any code that assumes exit()ing will end the program.

Comment: Je Rog: require will guarantee that the file is only included once, do doesn't provide such guarantees.

Comment: How do you find the typeglob of Perl's built in function in the first place?Are they all in `CORE::GLOBAL::exit` package?

Comment: Actually, you can trap the exit call, as shown in my answer herein. The difficulty is that some code not under your control may call exit and not die.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done this, but you might be able to redefine perl's **exit** function with your own that does a die() of a message your main code is aware of. You would then use CORE::exit(), if I remember, to get a true exit.

Better would be to run the new code in a package other than main:: so you don't corrupt main::s exit.

2011-Aug-06 update: for giggles I tried it:

```
my $code = qq[print qq(hello exit 99\n); exit 99;];  

{
  package Foo; 
  local $@;
  use vars qw(*exit);   #required
  local *exit = sub { die "TRAPPED EXIT: @_\n"; };  #override local to package Foo;
  print "doing eval\n"; 
  eval $code; 
  print "reason=$@\n";
}

print "done\n";       #prove we did not truly exit
exit 2;               #set specific exit code
```

And yes, Safe.pm is nice for untrusted code, but if the code is trusted, this is easier.

```
perl exit.pl; echo $?
doing eval
hello exit 99
reason=TRAPPED EXIT: 99
done
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Safe.pm` module. It allows you to restrict which operators can be executed . It was meant for situations where you need to execute untrusted code.