# Why I can't override the builtin print of Perl?

Tags: perl

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898805/how-to-ensure-my-code-never-exits-directly/6899010#6899010),

I tried to override `print` with my own:

```
BEGIN {*CORE::GLOBAL::print = sub {print 1};}
print 2;
```

But it turns out that it doesn't work,`2` is still printed instead of `1`.

Why?

Answer (score 13):

Because it has very special parsing rules that cannot be replicated by a normal function, the `print` operator cannot be overridden.

```
print "foo\n";
print { *STDOUT } "foo\n";
```

You can find out which operators can be overriden using [`prototype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/prototype.html)

```
>perl -E"say qq{$_: }, defined(prototype(qq{CORE::$_})) ? 'yes' : 'no' for @ARGV" print map time chr
print: no
map: no
time: yes
chr: yes
```

PS — You'd have an infinite loop if your code had actually overridden `print`.

Comment: @new_perl, Because it does not have special parsing rules that cannot be replicated by a normal sub. (It has prototype `;$`.)

Comment: Why you check `CORE::exit` while `exit` actually refers to `CORE::GLOBAL::exit`?

Comment: @new_perl, 1) Because that's what the document says. Did you not follow the link I provided? 2) Because `CORE::GLOBAL::exit` and `exit` aren't the same. `CORE::exit` and `exit` are equivalent. `CORE::GLOBAL::exit()` won't even work.

Comment: If that's the case,why `exit` can be overriden by override `CORE::GLOBAL::exit`, according to the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898805/how-to-ensure-my-code-never-exits-directly/6899010#6899010

Comment: @new_perl, Because that's what `CORE::GLOBAL::exit` does.

Comment: Can you explain a little more the relation between `CORE::GLOBAL::exit` and `CORE::exit`?

Comment: @new_perl, `CORE::GLOBAL::exit` is used to override `CORE::exit`.

Comment: Do you mean I can override all builtins `xxx` (that can be overriden in the first place) can be overriden by `CORE::GLOBAL::xxx`?

Answer (score 10):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678882/which-perl-built-ins-cannot-be-overridden-in-coreglobal/3678957#3678957) to another question:

> The following keywords cannot be overridden:
>
> `chop, defined, delete, do, dump, each, else, elsif, eval, exists, for, foreach, format, glob, goto, grep, if, keys, last, local, m, map, my, next, no, package, pop, pos, print, printf, prototype, push, q, qq, qw, qx, redo, return, s, scalar, shift, sort, splice, split, study, sub, tie, tied, tr, undef, unless, unshift, untie, until, use, while, y`

Comment: By the way, they can be overridden by another means: `PL_keyword_plugin`. [feature::qw_comments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature::qw_comments) overrides `qw`, for example.